# Parameter corruption when interfacing FORTRAN lapack routine

Tags: fortran, heap-memory, lapack, heap-corruption

I'm stucked with a heap corruption problem in Visual Studio 2008 with Intel Fortran Compiler 11. I'm working on Windows 7 64-bit.

This is a call to a (F77) lapack subroutine in my F90 program:

```
  call dgetrs('N', nbParams, one, a, nbParams, ipv, x, nbParams, err)
```

Before this call the debugger shows expected values for all parameters. a and x stand for two "allocatable" variables with size (nbParams,nbParams) and (nbParams) respectively.

However, after running this line the execution stops with an Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000001. Since I have compiled lapack in debug mode I'm able to go inside the call, and I see that everything but 'TRANS' gets corrupted just in the first statement of DGETRS.

```
  SUBROUTINE DGETRS( TRANS, N, NRHS, A, LDA, IPIV, B, LDB, INFO )
  ...
  CHARACTER          TRANS
  INTEGER            INFO, LDA, LDB, N, NRHS
  ...
  INTEGER            IPIV( * )
  DOUBLE PRECISION   A( LDA, * ), B( LDB, * )
  ......
  INFO = 0     **--> Now all input vars but TRANS are corrupted or dereferenced!**
```

I'm tried everything and I'm unable to locate the problem. Could anybody help me locating the problem?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: what are the types of the actual arguments to `dgetrs`? Lapack is not gentle in handling parameter type mismatches

Comment: can you add the declaration of the vars you have in the caller, and how you perform the allocation ?

Comment: integer nbParams, one, err; double precision, dimension(:), pointer :: x; double precision, dimension(:,:), allocatable :: x; allocate(x(nbParams), stat=err); integer, dimension(:), allocatable            :: ipv; Then I allocate memory for arrays: allocate(a(nbParams,nbParams), stat=err); allocate(ipv(nbParams), stat=err);

Comment: Was the previous call to DGETRF successful?

Comment: Yes, it was (the corresponding INFO value was zero and returned variables had good values).

Comment: @TomasGuardabrazoPedroche: can you try it declaring `x` as an `allocatable` array rather than `pointer`?

Comment: I've tried, but the problem persists.

Comment: BTW, nbParams=202 so we are dealing with big sizes. I'm compiling with -heap-arrays and linking with /STACK:400000 just in case, but it does not change anything.

Comment: Would you post a minimal compilable example, demonstrating the problem?

Answer (score 0):

This kind of problems usually appear when using assumed shape arrays without an interface. Try declaring an interface such as:

```
INTERFACE
   SUBROUTINE DGETRS( TRANS, N, NRHS, A, LDA, IPIV, B, LDB, INFO )
    CHARACTER          TRANS
    INTEGER            INFO, LDA, LDB, N, NRHS
    INTEGER            IPIV( * )
    DOUBLE PRECISION   A( LDA, * ), B( LDB, * )
  END SUBROUTINE
END INTERFACE
```